# Python/Scrapy How to go into a deeper link and go back

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrap information about every firm in from this website : www.canadianlawlist.com

I have finished most of it, but I am running into a small problem.

I am trying to get the results to display in the following order :

```
-Firm Name and Information

 *Employees from the firm Information.
```

But instead I am getting very random results.

It will scrape information about 2 firms and then scrap the information of employees. Like that :

```
-Firm Name and Information
-Firm name and information
  *Employee from Firm 1
-Firm name and information
  *Employee from Firm 2
```

It goes something like that . I am not sure what i am missing in my code :

```
def parse_after_submit(self, response):

    basicurl = "canadianlawlist.com/"
    products = response.xpath('//*[@class="searchresult_item_regular"]/a/@href').extract()
    for p in products:
        url = "http://canadianlawlist.com" + p
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_firm_info)

        #process next page
    #for x in range(2, 6):
     #   next_page_url = "https://www.canadianlawlist.com/searchresult?searchtype=firms&city=montreal&page=" + str(x)

def parse_firm_info(self,response):

        name =  response.xpath('//div[@class="listingdetail_companyname"]/h1/span/text()').extract_first()
        print name 
        for info in response.xpath('//*[@class="listingdetail_contactinfo"]'):

            street_address = info.xpath('//div[@class="listingdetail_contactinfo"]/div[1]/span/div/text()').extract_first()
            city = info.xpath('//*[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()').extract_first(),
            province = info.xpath('//*[@itemprop="addressRegion"]/text()').extract_first(),
            postal_code = info.xpath('//*[@itemprop="postalCode"]/text()').extract_first(),
            telephone = info.xpath('//*[@itemprop="telephone"]/text()').extract_first(),
            fax_number = info.xpath('//*[@itemprop="faxNumber"]/text()').extract_first(),
            email = info.xpath('//*[@itemprop="email"]/text()').extract_first(),

            print street_address
            print city
            print province
            print postal_code
            print telephone
            print fax_number
            print email

            for people in response.xpath('////div[@id="main_block"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]'):    

                pname = people.xpath('//*[@class="listingdetail_individual_item"]/h3/a/text()').extract()
                print pname

            basicurl = "canadianlawlist.com/"
            employees = response.xpath('//*[@class="listingdetail_individual_item"]/h3/a/@href').extract()
            for e in employees:
                url2 = "http://canadianlawlist.com" + e
                yield scrapy.Request(url2, callback=self.parse_employe_info)


def parse_employe_info(self,response):

                    ename = response.xpath('//*[@class="listingdetail_individualname"]/h1/span/text()').extract_first()
                    job_title = response.xpath('//*[@class="listingdetail_individualmaininfo"]/div/i/span/text()').extract_first()
                    print ename
                    print job_title
```

Comment: Why do you print your information? You should yield a dictionary with all of the items and then you can save it all data as json or csv file: `scrapy crawl spider -o output.json`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on the order Python's `print` function when it comes to concurrent programming. If you care about standard output order you need to use `logging` module.

Scrapy has shortcut function for that in `Spider` class:

```
import scrapy
import logging

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log("first message", level=logging.INFO)
        self.log("second message", level=logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy run multiple requests at the same time, so the content displayed on the console can be corresponding to any the multiple requests running at same time. 
You can go to settings.py and set

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
```

Now only one request will be launched at a time so your console will show meaningful data but this will make the scraping slower.